# Pass second scope to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have little problem that took me hours already to find a solution, 
I have a JSON which returns me names of pages + some information about it i pass it to the directive and everything works find, until i tried to add another scope to the directive displaying those items form JSON, items form json display as usual but the second scope with url of my page is not. What Am i doing wrong?

IN ANGULAR CONTROLLER 
 `pageURL = 'blabla.com';
 $scope.pageURL = pageURL;`

ANGULAR DIRECTIVE

```
    }).directive('itsearchresult', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            result: '=result',
            pageURL: '@pageURL'
        },
        templateUrl: 'SearchResults.html'
    };

})
```

HTML

```
<itsearchresult result="result" pageURL="pageURL"></itsearchresult>
```

searchResults.html

```
<div ng-if="result != 2">

<h3 ng-if='result.nameWP == undefined'> <a href="{{pageURL}}{{result.name}}">
{{result.name}}</a></h3>
<h3 > <a href="{{pageURL}}{{result.postID}}">{{result.nameWP}}</a></h3> 

...{{result.content}}...
```

link -> {{pageURL}} <- THIS little piece of 'art' doesn't show :(

Please help me, i really dont want to hang myself today.

Comment: use `snake casing`(my-directive) while passing the param and `camel case` inside directive (myDirective)

Comment: looks like a typo error. On HTML you need to call your parameter page-url if you directives defines it as pageUrl . Pay attention to the MAJ on directives Scope.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right, I already solve my issue, with answer below, but thanks for your time ::)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you are doing nothing with your directive, you should remove that directive's scope and let it use parent's scope.

```
}).directive('itsearchresult', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: 'SearchResults.html'
    };

})

<itsearchresult></itsearchresult>
```

And now all calls here must be to your controller scope

```
<h3 ng-if='result.nameWP == undefined'> <a href="{{pageURL}}{{result.name}}">
{{result.name}}</a></h3>
<h3 > <a href="{{pageURL}}{{result.postID}}">{{result.nameWP}}</a></h3> 

...{{result.content}}...
```

And quick solution to you is rename page-url key

```
<itsearchresult result="result" page-url="pageURL"></itsearchresult>
```

And in your directive

```
}).directive('itsearchresult', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            result: '=result',
            pageUrl: '@pageUrl'
        },
        templateUrl: 'SearchResults.html'
    };

})
```

Comment: OMG :O, it's working, thank you!. So the problem was with bad scope implementation in my directive?

Comment: Yeah, it's like the other answer's explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.. For creating custom directive camel case is best practice.

> AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

```
 directive('itsearchresult', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            result: '=result',
            pageUrl: '@pageUrl'
        },
        templateUrl: 'SearchResults.html'
    };

<itsearchresult result="result" page-url="{{pageURL}}"></itsearchresult>
```